# Java Application in JFrame gets stuck after StartMenu

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I have made a game with 20+ classes in it and if I run the application in Eclipse it perfectly works.

Now if I export the game to a runnable jar, it gets stuck when I try to launch the game. But the weird thing is that my intro plays and I can continue by pressing "enter" to my menu, but if I try to start the game from there, the menu gets stuck. (normally the background of my menu moves)

So, I have three `GameState` wich are called `introState`, `menuState` and `level1State`. These three all extend from GameState. introState and menuState work perfectly but level1State doesn't.

I'll put the code from level1State and the manifestfile here. Eclipse doesn't give me any errors.

My game does have a Main-class and every class displayed does exist and works.

Any ideas on what causes this and how to solve this? Or maybe another way to play this game outside eclipse?

package GameState;

```
import Main.GamePanel;
import TileMap.*;
import Entity.*;
import Entity.Enemies.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

package GameState;

import Main.GamePanel;
import TileMap.*;
import Entity.*;
import Entity.Enemies.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Level1State extends GameState {

    private TileMap tileMap;
    private Background bg;

    private Player player;

    private ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;

    private HUD hud;

    public Level1State(GameStateManager gsm) {
        this.gsm = gsm;
        init();
    }

    public void init() {

        tileMap = new TileMap(30);
        tileMap.loadTiles("/Tilesets/darktheme.gif");
        tileMap.loadMap("/Maps/level1-1.map");
        tileMap.setPosition(0, 0);
        tileMap.setTween(1);

        bg = new Background("/Backgrounds/backgroundbg.gif", 0.1);

        player = new Player(tileMap);
        player.setPosition(100, 100);

        populateEnemies();

        hud = new HUD(player);

    }

    private void populateEnemies() {

        enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();


        Slugger s;
        Point[] points = new Point[] {
            new Point(860, 200),
            new Point(1525, 200),
            new Point(1680, 200),
            new Point(1800, 200)
        };
        for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            s = new Slugger(tileMap);
            s.setPosition(points[i].x, points[i].y);
            enemies.add(s);
        }



        Spin s1;
        Point[] point = new Point[]{
                new Point(1990,100)
        };
        for(int k = 0; k < point.length; k ++){
            s1 = new Spin(tileMap);
            s1.setPosition(point[k].x, point[k].y);
            enemies.add(s1);
            //System.out.println(point[k].y);
        }


    }

    public void update() {

        // update player
        player.update();
        tileMap.setPosition(
            GamePanel.WIDTH / 2 - player.getx(),
            GamePanel.HEIGHT / 2 - player.gety()
        );

        // set background
        bg.setPosition(tileMap.getx(), tileMap.gety());

        // attack enemies
        player.checkAttack(enemies);

        // update all enemies
        for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
            Enemy e = enemies.get(i);
            e.update();
            if(e.isDead()) {
                enemies.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }

    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

        // draw bg
        bg.draw(g);

        // draw tilemap
        tileMap.draw(g);

        // draw player
        player.draw(g);

        // draw enemies
        for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
            enemies.get(i).draw(g);
        }

        // draw hud
        hud.draw(g);

    }

    public void keyPressed(int k) {
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) player.setLeft(true);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) player.setRight(true);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) player.setUp(true);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) player.setDown(true);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) player.setJumping(true);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_E) player.setGliding(true);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_A) player.setScratching();
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_F) player.setFiring();
    }

    public void keyReleased(int k) {
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) player.setLeft(false);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) player.setRight(false);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) player.setUp(false);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) player.setDown(false);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) player.setJumping(false);
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_E) player.setGliding(false);
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: Main.Game
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Comment: How does TilesMap work? How does Background work? What do you mean by gets stuck...

Comment: Have a look at this question : stackoverflow.com/questions/1662686/

Comment: @MadProgrammer The background of my menu moves until I select start. I also can't choose any other option after I selected start. This is a link to the project: https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropboxusercontent.com%2Fu%2F59779278%2FDragon%2520Tale%2520Tutorial%2520P08.rar&redir_token=7ZA7nGuqMuVKrNQgLoC1O3s_iUF8MTQyNDcyODkzOEAxNDI0NjQyNTM4

It uses the same engine

Comment: @Johan It does load the image of the menu and the intro so that can't be the problem... Or can it?

Comment: Casper, I exported it, and ran it, and it worked fine for me. I pressed start game, and there were no problems. What happen for you?

Comment: What I really want to know is how does it load the images?  Where are the images within your project?

Comment: @MadProgrammer They are in the packages

Comment: And how are they been loaded?

Comment: @MadProgrammer BufferedImage spritesheet = ImageIO.read(
    getClass().getResourceAsStream(
     "/Sprites/Player/playersprites.gif"
    )
   );

Comment: And `ImageIO` doesn't throw any errors?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No I downloaded his project, imported it, no errors only some warnings. then i exported it as a "Runnable jar file" from eclipse and stared it. To me it worked great and I didn't encounter the problems he describred.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Does that mean that my eclipse isn't working properly?

Comment: @Johan How did you make the runnable jar? If I export it as runnable jar in eclipse, it still won't work

Comment: @CasperVranken If you right click on it, then press export. then choose java, and after that you can choose either jar or RUNNABLE jar, you take runnable. when i exported it to desktop and played first level, but I don't know how to get to the second level x)

Comment: @Johan Still working on level 2 :) and I found my mistake. I missed a capital letter in my version of the game :( that was a sad moment

Comment: @CasperVranken hahahahha I understand that must have sucked xD nice game though! Did you make it in Slick?

Comment: I did not actually :) I made it in eclipse! and thank you :) The version you opened wasn't mine though, my graphics suck a bit more.. but the gameplay is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

DId you export it as a runnable JAR or as a JAR file? Try both if you haven't yet. I use the same engine and it works for me but i exported it as a jar it didn't work completely while when I exported it as a runnable JAR file it does work.

Comment: Also, check how you structure your code. Maybe you should try adding the spin to a different arraylist and add them in seperatly